# grub having problems with Windows7 booting

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub

I installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my laptop. It was working properly until yesterday. I went to do some work after I switched on my laptop and selected Windows, but when I came back my laptop's battery was dead. I charged it and when I tried to get into Windows the screen goes black and comes back to the grub boot screen again. Now I can only use Ubuntu.

How do I fix it so that I can boot into windows again?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [GRUB boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) first. It will rewrite the MBR and bootloader after scanning the hard drive for bootable partitions.

The next thing would be to do a Windows Repair. Insert the Windows CD and boot from that. When the menu comes up, select Repair Windows. If the repair is successful, you will likely only be able to boot into Windows. You will then need the GRUB boot repair as mentioned above.

Comment: You will want to reverse that order since repairing the Windows Bootloader after Grub would actually result in the replacement of Grub.